# Problem with ST_Union

Tags: postgis, raster

I have loaded some rasters into Postgis. I did a lot of ST_XXXX (scale, snap to grid,resample) magic to make them aligned. After executing:

```
select  
r1.rid,r2.rid 
,ST_NotSameAlignmentReason(r1.rast,r2.rast)
,ST_SameAlignment(r1.rast,r2.rast) 
from 
  rasters.r r1, 
  rasters.r r2
where not ST_SameAlignment(r1.rast,r2.rast)
```

I got nothing, if I remove:

> where not ST_SameAlignment(r1.rast,r2.rast)

all I got is

> "The rasters are aligned"

Which seems ok, but when I execute:

```
SELECT ST_Union(rast,'FIRST') from rasters.r
```

I got:

> rt_raster_from_two_rasters: The two rasters provided do not have the
>   same alignment

Why ?

Postgres 9.4

"POSTGIS="2.1.8 r13780" GEOS="3.5.0-CAPI-1.9.0 r4090" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.11.1, released 2014/09/24" LIBXML="2.7.8" LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" RASTER"

Comment: How many rasters do you have in your table? Did you try to isolate two of them having the problem?

Comment: 26, I did tried, if I remove one (18th) all the rest will be ok, then if I add 18 and remove some others (10,11,12,13) ST_Union works fine (I did not managed to isolate a particular pair that is not ok): 
`DO $$
declare
 l_buffer               raster;
 i integer;
 j integer;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..26 LOOP 
    FOR j IN 1..26 LOOP 
      if i<>j then
        RAISE NOTICE '% %',i,j;    
        select ST_Union(rast) into l_buffer
          from rasters.r
        where rid=i or rid=j;
      end if;  
    end loop;   
  end loop; 
END $$;`  
Query returned successfully with no result in 21:07 minutes